# jQuery - Add row to table, check contents if already in the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having a challenge in jQuery/html. Hope you can guide me.

Let me describe my scenario:

I have a table where I can add a new row on button click.

Each row has two columns. Each column has a select list/drop down list.

the first column has  a select list of modules: (Delivery, Inventory, etc..)
the second column has a select list of actions: (View, Edit, Delete)

So basically it is a table with list of modules and actions that a user can access/perform.

Here's what I want to do. For example, I have a row, and in the first column(module) it has **Delivery** as value. In the second column(action) it has **View** as value.

Now, if I added a new row, the **Delivery** value should still show in the module list, but the **View** value should no longer show in the action list since it is already selected.

It is like, if I add a new row, it will look for existing values, and it will not show in the list anymore.

The values of the select lists (module and action) came from a database.

Hope I have explained myself clearly. I am using PHP and jQuery. Please see my code and screenshot of the table. Thanks, any help and suggestion would be appreciated.

```js
  $('#add-row').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $("#role-detail").each(function () {
       var tds = '<tr>';
       jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
          tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
       });
       tds += '</tr>';
       if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
        $('tbody', this).append(tds);
       } else {
           $(this).append(tds);
       }
     });   
  });
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn btn-secondary" id="add-row">Add Row</a>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hovered table-striped" id="role-detail">
  <thead>
    <th>Module Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Delivery</option>
          <option>Inventory</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Add</option>
          <option>Edit</option>
        </select>          
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB8Hh.png)

Comment: so basically, you want to duplicate last row selections when clicking Add Row?

Comment: Hi @kasperite, no, the value should still show, but not selected. Example:  the Delivery module has 3 actions (View Edit Delete). If I add a row, and selected Delivery module and View as action, and I add another row, I can still select Delivery module but the View action should not be in the list anymore, Edit and Delete only.

Comment: gotcha!what do you expect if you runs out of actions ie adding 4th Delivery row?

Comment: @kasperite, Nice! the Delivery module should not be available anymore. I am thinking of saving the current row in the database if I click row add. And at the same time do another ajax call to populate the new row. So if I click row add, it will perform save, and retrieve values to populate the select lists. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: are you saving the data in your database?

Comment: how about create an array of object `[{name:view, used:true}...]` and update used value when they are used and render only `used:false` when new row is created. Does get slightly more complicated if u wanna delete rows too

Comment: Hello, yeah it's getting complicated. But I have changed my design to checkboxes. Something like Drupal. Asking here makes me think of other solutions. Thanks for your suggestions I appreciate it. I will get back soon if I encountered new challenges. Thanks!

Comment: After a lot of thought, I have come to a similar conclusion conclusion - that a `<select>` menu is not the right thing for `View, Edit, Delete`. 
As discrete buttons (or maybe checkboxes), they will indeed be far simpler to manage, and will provide a better UI.